# PDF as a map in Leaflet JS?

Tags: javascript, pdf, leaflet

I'm wondering if it's possible to upload a PDF document to use as a map in Leaflet, or if it needs to be converted to another format first? I've only seen examples that actually reference a map like this:

```
 // initialize the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([42.35, -71.08], 13);

// base map
L.tileLayer('http://tiles.mapc.org/basemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{
  attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>, Data by <a href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
  maxZoom: 17,
  minZoom: 9
}).addTo(map);

// bike lanes
L.tileLayer('http://tiles.mapc.org/trailmap-onroad/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{
  maxZoom: 17,
  minZoom: 9
}).addTo(map);
```

Docs: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html

Comment: Does Leaflet come with any documentation?

Comment: It does but I didnt see anything about this type of usage. Updated question

Comment: I see that `GridLayer` can "be extended to create a tiled grid of HTML elements like <canvas>, <img> or <div>", suggesting it is *possible*. Keep in mind, though, that a very heavy, slow drawing PDF may not be the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: No.

---

PDFs are complex to view - they are not one simple HTML element. This is because there is no "one true view" of a PDF. Do you want to display one page, multiple pages, the table of contents as text, one image of one specific page? Without knowing that, it's not possible to have a one-PDF-file-to-one-HTML-element mapping. Which means there's no way to tell Leaflet what to display.

*In theory*, one could leverage [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to parse the PDF file, select some specific content, and then spawn some HTML elements as appropriate. However, the cost of doing so **far exceeds** the cost of exporting the data to some other format better suited for GIS work.